# Split string "A10" into char 'A' and int 10

Tags: c++, c, string

Given a string consisting of a single character followed by a number (one or two digits), I would like to split it into a character and an integer. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

My thoughts so far:

I can easily grab the character like so:

```
string mystring = "A10";
char mychar = mystring[0];
```

The hard part seems to be grabbing the one or two digit number that follows.

Comment: Actually no, believe it or not. I'm building a battleship program for practice and need to grab the index of the cells. "A1" - "J10"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/), [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/), [c_str](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cplusplus.com%2Freference%2Fstring%2Fstring%2Fc_str%2F&ei=uGvaS_yaCpKyswOoq727DQ&usg=AFQjCNFxJouHWm1VIWFA3G90VbXUZtLjfQ&sig2=NYZI0mTu0hj_GZpMU8a39g) and [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) as:

```
string s = "A10";
char c = s[0]; // c is now 'A'
int n = atoi((s.substr(1,2)).c_str()); // n is now 10
```

**EDIT:**

The above will also work if `s="A1"`. This is because *if the `2nd` argument to `substr` makes  the substring to span past the end of the string content, only those characters until the end of the string are used.*

Answer (score 17):

```
#include <sstream>

char c;
int i;    
std::istringstream ss("A10");
ss >> c >> i;//First reads char, then number.
             //Number can have any number of digits. 
             //So your J1 or G7 will work either.
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but shouldn't you be able to do ss >> c >> i; ?

Comment: I'd also use the input operator to grab the char: `std::istringstream ss("A10"); char c; int i; ss >> c >> i;` This method keeps the extraction consistent.  (@Zan Lynx beat me to the punch, but I actually tried it first!)

Answer (score 2):

### Using [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

```
std::string s = "A10";
int i;
char c;
sscanf(s.c_str(), "%c%d", &c, &i);
/* c and i now contain A and 10 */
```

This is more of a "C way" of doing things, but works none-the-less.

Here is a more "C++ way":

```
std::string s = "A10";
std::cout << *s.begin() << s.substr(1, s.size()) << std::endl;
/* prints A10 */
```